# What is $\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2^n})$ in terms of $\cos(\pi t)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

If it is easier, you can do it the other way around, by writing $\cos(\pi t)$ in terms of $\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2^n})$. I just wanted to know if there was a nice closed form solution to a problem like this, and, if so, how many terms scale up with how large $n$ scales up.

Comment: I would expect many square roots.

Comment: Would going the other way around create a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: You mean express $\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2^n})$ in terms of $\cos(\pi t)$?

Comment: Yes, or writing $\cos(\pi t)$ in terms of $\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2^n})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\cos(\pi t)$ in terms of $\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2^n})$ ... the same thing as writing $\cos(2^n\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$ ... is a [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition)

Comment: And inverting that would mean taking the square root of the average with 1, $n$ times.